# How to update the text(single view) in listview via service android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service

I have a list with images and text, Text change in every 1-2 second .I have a custom adapter class which extends the `BaseAdpater` class. I want to update only the `textview` in `listrow` as data change.

I am using broadcast receiver which register when activity start and give back result in every 2 second which i want to display in listview.

The problem is when i call `notifyDataSetChanged` the whole `listview` get refreshed including icons and another `textview` and hang for   1-2 second. There is a big performance issue.

please give suggestion how can i handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
private void updateSingleRow(int listrow, String newText){
  View view = yourListView.getChildAt(listrow - yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
  TextView yourText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
  yourText.setText(newText);
}
```

Comment: the index of the item you want to update ;) you wrote in your question something about a listrow

Comment: i have two different classes one is activity and other is customAdpater class. so i want to change the text of lisview rows which are currently visible to user . How to get that position(litsrow)?

Comment: Then use ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() and ListView.getLastVisiblePosition() and remove getFirstVisiblePosition from the method.. iterate between the indexes and always call that method.

Comment: Did u write a ViewHolder? They are used to increase the speed in your ListView: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: yes i did. As soon as brodcast receiver receive the array of data i call your method however it does change the textview correct but when scrolling it hangs for 1-2 second and same result when using `notifyDataSetChanged`